# How to get minimal jQuery slideshow to slide properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to make this minimal jQuery slideshow ([Simple jQuery slideshow using animate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396899/simple-jquery-slideshow-using-animate)), **but how do I make the 3rd and 4th image slide "together" like in the 1st and 2nd image?**

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/eku4Lwt1/44/

JS:

changeSlide(1, $(".slideshow img"));

```
function changeSlide(i, items) {
    setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
          var currentItem = items.eq(i),
            prevItem = items.eq(i-1);

          prevItem.css("left", -prevItem.width());
          currentItem.css("right", 0);

          changeSlide(i+1, items);
      }, 2000);    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow" style="height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/101" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/102" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;                  
}
.slideshow img:first-child {
    left: 0;
}
```

Ideally they should slide like in this [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) example (although I feel Slick is overkill for this job):

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/eku4Lwt1/2/

Comment: i dont see anything "Sliding" in your first jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `-moz-transition`, please try now.

Comment: Is working fine for me, what is the issue?

Comment: @IrvinDominin 1st and 2nd image works fine. 3rd and 4th is all messed up. You're on the first fiddle I posted right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code quite a bit: [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/eku4Lwt1/48/)

First of all, you should do `prevItem.css("right", prevItem.width());` instead of `prevItem.css("left", -prevItem.width());`. And CSS should be changed like this: 
`.slideshow img:first-child {
    right: 0px;
}`

I have also changed the animation to circularly repeat. Dunno if you can use it, otherwise here is what you asked for http://jsfiddle.net/eku4Lwt1/56/

Comment: Greetings Semyon and thank you for your suggestions! Would it be possible to make it non-circular though? And also for the slides to actually slide like in the Slides.js example? Also incase you're wondering, this code was first crafted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396899/simple-jquery-slideshow-using-animate.

Comment: Please see the second link, that was posted at the end of my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/eku4Lwt1/56/

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/eku4Lwt1/64/

In your JS change this line:

```
currentItem.css("right", 0);
```

->

```
currentItem.css("left", 0);
```

And in your CSS change the image positioning to `left: 200px;`:

```
.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! Have to give this one to Semyon though as he answered first, despite this actually being your code.

Comment: Henri's and my solutions are different, as I'm using right offset while Henri is using left. The both offsets shouldn't be used at the same time.

Comment: Greetings! Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205299/making-minimal-js-css-slideshow-responsive -- trying to improve this slider a little..